# Checking Total Values of Fields = Total Quantity in Form

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am creating a form and have 1 Total Quantity and 3 other separate fields.

I would like to check and prompt when user input is more than the Total Quantity.

Example:

Total Quantity: 10

Site 1: 5

Site 2: 3

Site 3: 1

If the total quantity of Site 1, Site 2 and Site 3 is more than 10, I would like to halt save data or prompt an error.

PS: New to Access 2016 currently, pardon if this is a basic question.

Thank you.

Comment: Use the BeforeUpdate event in your form to check the calculation. You can set Cancel=True to stop the update.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Fiddled around, got it as you said. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set form's *Before Update* event to "[Event Procedure]" and the actual field names inside the brackets `[]` below.

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    With Me
        If Nz(![Site 1], 0) + Nz(![Site 2], 0) + Nz(![Site 3], 0) > ![Total Quantity] Then
            Cancel = True
            MsgBox "Invalid quantity."
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Yeap, got it... fiddled with it yesterday. Got it working. Thank you. :)

Comment: Just to add.. I tried not equal to as in the combined total should be the same as Total Quantity. I tried != but there is an error. Am I using the wrong operator?

Comment: Not equal in VBA is `<>` :)

Comment: However, note not equal will be True if the value is less or more.

Comment: Ahhhh.... that was the problem! Thank you so much. I got all the operators mixed. Thanks again, much appreciated.